# How to use a virtual machine to access an OS from a second HD?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, virtual-machine, multi-boot

I am going to have a computer with two 1TB hard drives. I plan on using 1 for Linux and the other for Windows. If I am using Linux, is it possible to have a Virtual Machine use the 1TB (windows) disk as the virtual disk drive?

I would like to be able to be able to have boot into Windows and access the exact same data and OS that I would access from the VM if I was booted into Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is probably not "Is it possible..." but "How do I set this up?". Please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible, look into creating virtual machines using raw disk back ends. Note that Windows often doesn't like the frequent hardware changes that being real and virtualized causes. It may not be stable in the long term.